# What's better to indicate a 'refresh' button?

Tags: gui-design

I am looking for a button to show 'refresh' in a web browser. The best options I've got so far are the following:

`↺` and `↻`

These are both unicode characters, and I'd like to keep them as text, not images.

Google Chrome uses the second option, but rotated as seen below.

[image: Google Chrome example]

So which is better from a design standpoint. My gut is telling me the second, but it doesn't look right.

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox uses the same as Google, same as Safari (in this case, slightly rotated counter clock wise) Either way, you'll need to test this yourself, right now this is just opinion based

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be overthinking this as the two solutions are very similar. But if you need a sliver of doubt to help decide between the two, I have an argument against the Refresh that spins counterclockwise. I would prefer the clockwise Refresh because the counterclockwise icon "could" be confused with an "UNDO" function. IMO, counterclockwise indicates that you can go back in time.

Comment: Just to add that Google's Material Design guidelines are with you on this one: "The refresh icon shows time moving forward; the direction is clockwise." https://material.io/guidelines/usability/bidirectionality.html#bidirectionality-rtl-mirroring-guidelines